# What does <%@ mean in JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm dissecting a JSP application I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/spring-finance-manager/) to try to learn more about it.

I come across a lot of `<%@...` but I'm not sure what it means and I can't find it explained anywhere.

For example in this context:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

What does angle bracket percentage sign at symbol mean?

Comment: That sir is a [Directive](http://www.jsptut.com/Directives.jsp)

Comment: That's what developers say in cartoons when their code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<%@ is the directive attribute. You may include a page or may declare a tag-library using <%@

More on it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm)

Answer (score 2):

These are directives use for including files , defines **page-dependent attributes**, such as **scripting language**, **error page**, and **buffering requirements** & declares a **tag library**, containing custom actions, used in the page.

The one you wrote is third one which declare **tag library**.